# Magento_Paypal - Error 404 on Customer Section load

Tags: payment-methods, paypal, magento2.3.2

After executing composer update, we were unable to use the **minibasket** and **customer links on our frontend**.

Investigating in the developer console showed a `404` for the url `/customer/section/load`.

The response is `{"message":"The element with the &quot;root&quot; ID wasn&#039;t found. Verify the ID and try again."}`.

It seems like the Paypal buttons in the Magento backend are responsible for the problem as i tried to comment out the shortcuts in `Magento_Paypal/Observer/AddPaypalShortcutsObserver.php:55 - 62` and the basket was fully functioning again.

This now leaves us with the issue of not having Paypal on our shop and i'm at a loss on how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that a third party module is at fault for this. I was able to track it down to the `core_layout_render_element` event by following the whole execution till `vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout:495` and with that found out which module: Amasty_GdprCookie. Problem is reported and will probably be fixed in the near future.